# Vertically align 3 images

Tags: html, css, image, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have 3 images that I want to align vertically however I can't seem to get it working properly. My images are split into 3 parts from 1 existing image. You can see slight transitions from one image to the other. What am I missing here?

HTML:

```
    <div id="Wrapper" class="Wrapper">
        <div id ="image-1">
            <img id="top" src="http://www.crystalcave.nl/wp-content/themes/shop-isle/top.png" class="jscolor border="0">
        </div>
        <div id ="image-2">
            <img id="mid" src="http://www.crystalcave.nl/wp-content/themes/shop-isle/mid.png" class="jscolor border="0">
        </div>
        <div id ="image-3">
            <img id="bot" src="http://www.crystalcave.nl/wp-content/themes/shop-isle/bot.png" class="jscolor border="0">
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/krvrp7eb/

Answer (score 2):

**Why this happens?**

`img` is an *inline* element and *inline elements flows like text*. The small whitespace is due to this. Possible solutions:

1. Change the display from `inline` to other - add `display: block` for instance
2. Change the `vertical-align` property to `top` (default is `baseline`)
3. Shrink the text size to 0 by `font-size: 0` on the containing block of the *inline* element.

**Example**

Add `vertical-align: top` to all the three images - see [`updated fiddle here`](https://jsfiddle.net/yvpy8n72/) and snippet below:

```css
#image-1 img,
#image-2 img,
#image-3 img {
  background-color: #00f;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.image-1,
.image-2,
image-3 {
  display: block;
}
.Wrapper {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="Wrapper" class="Wrapper">
  <div id="image-1">
    <img id="top" src="http://www.crystalcave.nl/wp-content/themes/shop-isle/top.png" class="jscolor" border="0">
  </div>
  <div id="image-2">
    <img id="mid" src="http://www.crystalcave.nl/wp-content/themes/shop-isle/mid.png " class="jscolor" border="0">
  </div>
  <div id="image-3">
    <img id="bot " src="http://www.crystalcave.nl/wp-content/themes/shop-isle/bot.png " class="jscolor" border="0">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just for clarification, font-size should be adjusted on the parent, in this case the wrapper, and not the img itself.

Comment: @ovokuro of course the *containing block* or wrapper... thanks for pointing that out...

Comment: I'm sorry that I explained it incorrectly. I'm not bothered by the small white spaces in between my images, I already got that part working in my website, however the small transitions at the sides of my images are with small edges. If you will look carefully you can see an edge like shape if the image were to be "whole". Also sorry for the very late reply. Christmas and all :D

Comment: no issues... I was able to get a *faint* border / outline in my Android browser  around each image - guess you are talking about that? Looks like this happens due to the image *rendering* in browsers...

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your CSS:

```
.Wrapper {
    font-size:0;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/0awaqLxg/)

Answer (score 1):

just add one css property in this

## image-1 img, #image-2 img, #image-3 img

to

float: left;

Answer (score 0):

use `position: relative;` and use top, bottom left, and right to adjust its position.